# Manually fire SpeechRecognizedEvent

Tags: c#, speech

I need to fire the SpeechRecognizedEvent manually for unit testing so I can't  use the EmulateSpeech Method from a SpeechRecognitionEngine

Edit:

I have already encapsulated the SpeechRecognition into a separate Class with its own interface to mock it.

I need to call the Event because I have an AutoResetEvent, which I Set() during the event. The Unit test needs this to proceed.

Comment: you just want to use SpeechRecoginzedEvent?

Comment: @Frenchy yes I want to use the SpeechRecognizedEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea with unit tests is not to use real things as they either:

1. Slow (e.g. database)
2. Dangerous to poke to often (e.g. Google Search API)
3. Not available (e.g. web service or hardware)

For such scenarios you suppose to use mocks/stubs. In other words things that behave identically, but in reality under your full control.

In your case `SpeechRecognitionEngine`, even if it might be available, would be too cumbersome for unit tests. Who/what would speak things to it? And even if you trigger an event, why to instantiate an instance of real `SpeechRecognitionEngine`?

Looking at MSDN for `SpeechRecognitionEngine` definition indicates that it doesn't implement an interface, which means it would be difficult to mock/stub.

For this case, you need to wrap, in other words, encapsulate `SpeechRecognitionEngine` into your own class which implements your interface. Then, all you need to do is to have two implementations of your interface, one with real `SpeechRecognitionEngine` for a real speech recognition, and another class for unit tests, which would just mimic your own callback, instead of using `SpeechRecognized` event.

You just swap one instance for another, and your code won't see a difference, as they are implementing single interface.

**If you just want to simulate an event**, you just call an event handler, as this is a method. Or another method, if you can't create some `EventArgs`. But the problem is that you'll have to expose inner methods from outside of your class (e.g. mark it `public` or `internal`), and this does looks nasty.

```
private void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ProcessSpeechRecognition(e.Result);
}

public void ProcessSpeechRecognition(RecognitionResult result)
{
    // your logic here
}
```

Then in test you just call something similar to the below:

```
ProcessSpeechRecognition(new RecognitionResult { Text = "test" });
```

Comment: I have edited my post with some additional information. The method you mentioned at the bottom of your post sadly doesn't work because the SpeechRecognizedEventArgs does not have a constructor, so you can't create a new instance of it

Comment: @Dardguy as you already realized, some APIs are non-test-friendly. This is more compelling reason to build test-friendly wrappers around non-test-friendly 3rd party classes. If you want to cut down on effort and just need quick and dirty way to test your code after event, just call your own method from event handler, and hope that you have no bug in the middle. Then call your own method from test, as event handler would do in real life scenario.

Comment: Another problem is that the RecognitionResult clas is sealed, so I am not able to substitute it. Do you have an idea how to to this in a clean way?

Comment: @Dardguy It looks like Microsoft already thought of this scenario. There's a simple way to emulate recognition event. Check out `SpeechRecognitionEngine.EmulateRecognize Method` this on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.emulaterecognize?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Despite posting an answer before that describes best practices for TDD; here is an answer specific to `SpeechRecognitionEngine`.

Microsoft has already thought about emulation of speech recognition. Here is MSDN article for `SpeechRecognitionEngine.EmulateRecognize Method`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.emulaterecognize